# Comparing two object's properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, comparison, deep-copy

I'm trying to learn Javascript and an exercise I'm doing is comparing two objects with a deep compare. I've checked to make sure they are both objects and I've compared the number of properties each of them have. Next, I'm trying to iterate over each of one object's properties and compare them each with all of the other object's properties. I'm not sure how to get the value of an object's properties and compare them with another object's properties, but I do know how to implement the properties iteration using a for/in loop. This is what I have so far.

```
function deepEqual(one, two) {

//They should both be objects.
  var bool1 = (typeof one == "object" && one != null);
  var bool2 = (typeof two == "object" && two != null);
  if(bool1 != bool2) {
    return one === two;
  }

  //If they don't have the same number
  //of properies, they are not equal.
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  for(oneProps in one) {
    num1++;
  }
  for(twoProps in two) {
    num2++;
  }
  if(num1 != num2) {
    return false;
  }

  //Here's where I'm stuck. I'm trying to
  //compare each of one's properties with each
  //of two's properties. If a property of one
  //doesn't match with any of two's, they are not equal.
  //I don't know how to implement this.
  for(x in one) {
    if(deepEqual(one[x], two[x]) == false) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Edit: I've changed the end to recurse deepEqual with each of the properties and I got a maximum call stack size error. I'm guessing something went wrong.

Comment: Re. “I’m not sure how to get the value of an object’s properties”: you can use array-indexing notation on objects, e.g. in your loop you can use `one[x]` to get the value of the property in question.

Comment: So, when I do that, would I use something like one[x] == two[x] or something similar?

Comment: Yeah, something like that would work, though if you’re trying to do some sort of ‘deep compare’ you’d recurse, of course. That said, I think deep comparison might be a bit trickier, since some objects contain themselves. But that’s a start, at least.

Comment: Right, so the maximum call-stack size issue is due to objects containing themselves. If you construct an object like so: `var x = {}; x.y = x;` and then call `deepEqual(x, x)`, it will find property `y` and try to compare it on both objects, which happen to be `x`, so it does `deepEqual(x, x)` again, on for eternity until it runs out of stack space. Unfortunately this is nontrivial to solve—some sort of memoization comes to mind as a possible solution.